# Java File API copy files across network

Tags: java, file, apache-commons

I've wrote some code to manipulate files with Java File and commons FileUtils API. It works fine if the files in local but not work always right if the files in anther machine. 
Can I use those File APIs across networks?

Comment: a possible answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12754020/813471

Comment: A better bet would be to use JDK 7 and implement `FileSystem` over these remote filesystems.