# Java. Get date of last file modification

Tags: java, ftp, timestamp

I try to get date of last file modification using `FTPClient` class:

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
client.connect(hostname);
client.login(user, passwd);
client.changeWorkingDirectory(dir);
FTPFile[] files = client.listFiles();

for (FTPFile file : files) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
    String formattedDate = formatDate.format(file.getTimestamp().getTime());
    System.out.println(file.getName() + "     " + file.getSize() + "     " + formattedDate);
}
```

At some files time is not printing correct: it is `00:00` instead of true value. Where is my mistake and how can I solve it? May be there are other methods to get this information?

I tried to implement same procedure using `URLConnection`:

```
String ftpUrl = "ftp://%s:%s@%s/%s";
String host = "ip address";
String user = "user name";
String pass = "password";
String filePath = "/folder name/";

ftpUrl = String.format(ftpUrl, user, pass, host, filePath);
System.out.println("URL: " + ftpUrl);
try {
    URL url = new URL(ftpUrl);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line;         // read from the urlconnection via the bufferedreader
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Files which had time `00:00` with `FTPClient` class now don't have it at all. Where is my mistake? May be it depends on file type?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Propably should tell us which FTPClient you're using? Guessing it's Apache commons-net? Have you checked the return value from `file.getTimeStamp()` and `file.getTimeStamp().getTime()` to verify what time they think it is?

Comment: Peter Liljenberg, yes. I used commons-net-3.3. `file.getTimeStamp().getTime()` returns something like `Sun Jun 01 00:00:00 EEST 2014`.

Comment: `file.getTimestamp()` returns `java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1401570000000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo`

Comment: `[id="Europe/Athens",offset=7200000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=138,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Athens,offset=7200000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-`

Comment: `1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2014,MONTH=5,WEEK_OF_YEAR=22,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_YEAR=152,DAY_OF_WEEK=1,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=7200000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]`

Comment: `file.getTimestamp().getTimeInMillis()` returns `1401570000000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this [Java FTP example - Get and set file modification time](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/java-ftp-example-get-and-set-file-modification-time)

Comment: user000324, how can access file using ip address and directory?

Comment: Try this `File inputFile = new File("\\your IP\path to file");`

Comment: I used this string instead of `filepath` in arguments of method `getModificationTime`: `ftp://user_name:password@ip_address//directory//` but the return result is `NULL`

Comment: From where u r accessing file, locally or remotely ?

Comment: Read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615475/basics-reading-writing-remote-files-using-java

Comment: I found how looks connection string but it doesn't help. I edited my post (question)

Comment: Have you tried this method of FTPClient `getLastModificationTimeDate(java.lang.String filePath)` ? It returns  last modification or update time of a file or a folder as a java.util.Date object.

Comment: I need to use zehon transfer pack?

Comment: No, it doesn't help. Result is the same.

Comment: See [Read file attributes using FTP protocol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24569861/java-read-file-attributes-using-ftp-protocol) post where @Goibniu told, **this code is susceptible to SQL injection attack**. Okey, look at this article [Java FTP example - Get details of a file or directory on server](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/java-ftp-example-get-details-of-a-file-or-directory-on-server). Now I hope you will get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Some FTP servers support `public String getModificationTime(String pathname)` on the `FTPClient` class. Maybe you could try this approach.

Comment: Wojtek O., how can access file using ip address and directory?

Comment: The same way as in [This Example](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/java-ftp-example-get-and-set-file-modification-time)