# how to access remote Linux machine through Java API

Tags: java, linux, api, centos

I need to access and run Linux commands on a remote **CentOS** machine through Java code. Please suggest me any API to access run the commands and also I need to get the output of the commands to be printed on the Java console.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Basics - reading/writing remote files using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615475/basics-reading-writing-remote-files-using-java)

Comment: You could use JSCH to call a remote SSH server.

Comment: @runDOSrun: thanks for responding. I was looking to run command and get it's output from a remote CentOS machine through Java, but in the question U marked duplicated they required to access file system. Please check the details before U mark duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) - it allows you to connect via SSH, execute commands remotely and transfer files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java `ProcessorBuilder` and `Process` classes to start an ssh process that executes remote command i.e. start an ssh process (e.g. `ssh  username@REMOTE_MACHINE 'CMD_ON_REMOTE_MACHINE'`) and read the output of the executed command using `getInputStream()` method of `Process` class.